# Only Enable TLSv1.2 on Tomcat 6.0.36

Tags: tls, tomcat

I need to make sure that a web app running on Tomcat 6.0.36 with Java 1.8 is only using TLS 1.2

1. As per documentation, I tried adjusting the Connector section in `server.xml`:
   `sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"` (I even set `sslEnabledProtocols`, even though it's ignored on this version of Tomcat).
2. In Configure Tomcat app, I have set (and various combinations of these):

   ```
   Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   ```
3. In Env Variables, I've set JAVA_OPTS

   - `Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"`
   - `Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

I have tried all combinations of these (spent days searching the web for solutions), and no luck.
Whenever I uncheck "Use TLS 1.0" from the "Advanced\Security" section in IE internet options, it stops working (even the Tomcat Status page is not accessible). I get the error:

> "This page can't be displayed. Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in Advanced Settings..."

This, in my opinion, is a sure sign that TLS1.0 is always (still) used.

Comment: Have you verified with `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443` or [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/)?

Comment: No, I haven't - I'm not allowed to install any third party tools. Thanks

Comment: `Connector.protocols` (but I think _not_ `sslProtocol`) should work -- but OTOH j8 should default to TLS1.0,1.1,1.2 with no config at all, and without a more accurate test tool than IE it's going to be hard to investigate. The other things you tried -- `https.protocols https.ciphersuites jdk.tls.client.protocols` -- only apply to (some) clients and are a waste of time for a server.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. For some reason, "sslProtocols" is not accepted at all.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/729407/272861